# Parallel.ForEach not adding items as expected in ConcurrentBag in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, asp.net-core-webapi, parallel.foreach

In my `Asp.Net Core WebApi Controller`, I'm receiving a `IFormFile[] files`. I need to convert this to of `List<DocumentData>`. I first used `foreach`. It was working fine. But later decided to change to `Parallel.ForEach` as I'm receiving many(>5) files.

**Here is my `DocumentData` Class:**

```cs
public class DocumentData
{
    public byte[] BinaryData { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

**Here is my `Parallel.ForEach` Logic:**

```cs
var documents = new ConcurrentBag<DocumentData>();
Parallel.ForEach(files, async (currentFile) =>
{
    if (currentFile.Length > 0)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await currentFile.CopyToAsync(ms);
            documents.Add(new DocumentData
            {
                BinaryData = ms.ToArray(),
                FileName = currentFile.FileName
            });
        }
    }
});
```

For Example, even for two files as input, `documents` always gives one file as output. Am I missing something?

I initially had `List<DocumentData>`. I found that it's not thread safe and changed to `ConcurrentBag<DocumentData>`. But still I'm getting unexpected results. Please assist on where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess it is because, `Parallel.Foreach` doesn't support `async/await`. It only takes `Action` as input and executes it for each item. And in case of async delegates it will execute them in a fire-and-forget manner. 
In that case passed lambda will be considered as `async void` function and `async void` can't be awaited.

If there were overload which takes `Func<Task>` then it would work.

I suggest you to create `Task`s with the help of `Select` and use `Task.WhenAll` for executing them at the same time.

For example:

```
var tasks = files.Select(async currentFile =>
{
    if (currentFile.Length > 0)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await currentFile.CopyToAsync(ms);
            documents.Add(new DocumentData
            {
                BinaryData = ms.ToArray(),
                FileName = currentFile.FileName
            });
        }
    }
});

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Additionally you can improve that code with just returning `DocumentData` instance from that method, and in such case there is no need to modify `documents` collection.  `Task.WhenAll` has overload which takes `IEnumerable<Task<TResult>` as input and produces `Task` of `TResult` array. So, the result will be so:

```
var tasks = files.Select(async currentFile =>
    {
        if (currentFile.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await currentFile.CopyToAsync(ms);
                return new DocumentData
                {
                    BinaryData = ms.ToArray(),
                    FileName = currentFile.FileName
                };
            }
        }

        return null;
    });

var documents =  (await Task.WhenAll(tasks)).Where(d => d != null).ToArray();
```

Comment: If you're using `Task.WhenAll`, then you need to `await` it.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev, now `ConcurrentBag<DocumentData>` is not needed right? Instead I can use `List<DocumentData>`

Comment: @fingers10 Sure, because `Parallel.ForEach` doesn't support async lambdas. You can use simple `foreach` for executing them sequentially, or `Task.WhenAll` for executing them concurrently

Comment: As a bonus, you can *return* the `DocumentData` from the `Select` lambda, and then `await Task.WhenAll(..)` will result in a `DocumentData[]`.

Comment: @StephenCleary Nice idea. Worth to update answer with that idea. Will do.

Answer (score 3):

You had the right idea with a *concurrent collection*, but misused a *TPL method*.

In short you need to be very careful about *async lambdas*, and if you are passing them to an `Action` or `Func<Task>`

Your problem is because `Parallel.For / ForEach` is not suited for the *async and await pattern* or *IO bound tasks*. They are suited for *cpu bound workloads*. Which means they essentially have `Action` parameters and let's the *task scheduler* create the *tasks* for you

If you want to run mutple tasks at the same time use `Task.WhenAll` , or a *TPL Dataflow* `ActionBlock` which can deal effectively with both *CPU bound* and *IO bound* works loads, or said more directly, they can deal with *tasks* which is what an async method is.

The fundimental issue is when you call an *async lambda* on an `Action`, you are essentially creating an `async void` method, which will run as a *task* unobserved. That's to say, your *TPL method* is just creating a bunch of *tasks* in parallel to run a bunch of *unobserved tasks* and not waiting for them.

Think of it like this, you ask a bunch of friends to go and get you some groceries, they in turn tell someone else to get your groceries, yet your friends report back to you and say thier job is done. It obviously isn't and you have no groceries.